# How to retrieve access token in IBM using AXIOS

Tags: javascript, axios, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to retrieve the access-token from IBM in my frontend UI application's console, using axios/fetch but facing CORS error. I got this API from this IBM documentation -> https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/iam-identity-token-api

`curl -X POST "https://iam.cloud.ibm.com/identity/token" --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --header 'Accept: application/json' --data-urlencode 'grant_type=urn:ibm:params:oauth:grant-type:apikey' --data-urlencode 'apikey=<API_KEY>'`

while trying to hit the above API call to retrieve access-token, getting the below error. Please help me to resolve this using AXIOS or fetch.

[image]

```
var data = 'grant_type=urn:ibm:params:oauth:grant-type:apikey&apikey=<API_KEY>';
const response = await axios({
    url: 'https://iam.cloud.ibm.com/identity/token',
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
    },
    data: data
});
console.log("Result", JSON.stringify(response));
access_token = response.data.access_token;
return await access_token;
```

Comment: IMHO you should not have any API key in the frontend for security reasons. So instead of addressing the technical issue, I recommend to reconsider the app architecture

Comment: I was trying this in my local. This is just to check the use case, I'll not use this code to production level.. so just want to resolve this issue and achieve this.

Comment: Ok, the error is independent of the API. It is a general security issue. Search for CORS questions and their answers.

Comment: instead of Bearer token I tried with Basic authorization in other api, that resolve the Cors error